# How to set attribute of member object of a realm model?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a realm object called `DiscoverUserInfo`:

```
class DiscoverUserInfo: Object , Mappable{

    dynamic var UserObject:User?
    dynamic var ConnectionStatus:Int = -1
    var PreviousMeetings = List<Meeting>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? { return "UserObject.UserId" }

}
```

Now for this, I want to set a primary key which is `UserId` of `UserObject`.

But when I run this code, I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   'Primary key property 'UserObject.UserId' does not exist on object
>   'DiscoverUserInfo''

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a primary key using a property of a dynamic variable. You'll have to do something like this:

```
class DiscoverUserInfo: Object , Mappable{

    dynamic var UserObject: User?
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var ConnectionStatus:Int = -1
    var PreviousMeetings = List<Meeting>()

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
     }

override class func primaryKey() -> String? { 
     return "id" 
     }

}
```

and then set the id to the associated UserObject's UserId each time you create a new DiscoverUserInfo object.

This is related to the issue of having no native support for compound primary keys in Realm. However, we expect to see this feature down the road.